# Adding options tag in multiselect tag through javascript in jsf

Tags: javascript, jsf, listbox

I am working on JSF page, I have two MultiSelectListbox in the page. On Multiselectlistbox is getting the value from the bean and the other listbox is empty. I have written the javascript code to add the selected item in one listbox from the other as an option tag. The problem is the option tag  is not getting added to the other listbox it just appears for a second and then goes away.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 function move(direction) {

  var src = document.getElementById('selectbox:left')
  var trg = document.getElementById('selectbox:right')
  var tem

  if (direction) {
   tem = src
   src = trg
   trg = tem
  }

  var selected = []

  for ( var i in src.options) {
   if (src.options[i].selected) {
    trg.options.add(new Option(src.options[i].text,
      src.options[i].value));
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Just do it in JSF instead of JS.

Comment: @BalusC can you provide me an example

Comment: Not with the question in its current form. There's too much ambiguity.

Comment: And if you don't do it in jsf (or at least server-side), you'll get an exception since the server does not know the added option and will think the data is tampered with on the client.

Comment: Thanks @Kukeltje . I read that some where. The only thing i can think of is to use ajax

Comment: Yep, and you can (should?) do an explicit check then if this user is allowed to add this specific option